# IIS: Where can I find the IIS logs?

Tags: iis, logging, iis-7, diagnostics

I'm trying to set up an application from a third party, which requires a supporting website hosted in my local IIS. I've created a website exactly as explained in their install guide, but am having some problems, and would like to see what the IIS log has to say. Embarrassingly enough, the problem is I can't find the log files!

So my question is: Where does IIS7 store logs by default?

Answer (score 562, accepted):

I think the default place for access logs is

```
%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles
```

Otherwise, check under IIS Manager, select the computer on the left pane, and in the middle pane, go under "Logging" in the IIS area. There you will se the default location for all sites (this is however overridable on all sites)

You could also look into

```
%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR
```

Which will contain similar log files that only represents errors.

Comment: Thanks, this seems logical, but the logs directory is empty. I probably need to turn on logging somehow, but I can't find anything about logging in the middle panel in IIS Manager.

Comment: If you don't find it, it isn't installed. You need to fire up `Programs and Features` then click on `Turn Windows features on or off` on the left side then select `Internet Information Services\World Wide Web Services\Health and Diagnostics\HTTP Logging`

Comment: You can check how it is configured on your computer this way: https://portal.smartertools.com/kb/a2487/where-are-my-iis-log-files-stored.aspx

Comment: I believe the latter path (...\HTTPERR) is the place where log files generated by http.sys land by default, not log files from IIS itself. See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784703%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Note that when you click "Logging" in IIS, have the site you're interested in selected...

Comment: This logs are useless if you are looking for error message.

Comment: Note: `%SystemDrive%` is _usually_ `C:`

Answer (score 120):

I believe this is an easier way of knowing where your IIS logs are, rather than just assuming a default location:

Go to your IIS site, e.g. Default, click on it, and you should see "Logging" to the right if logging is enabled:

[image]

Open it and you should see the folder right there:

[image]

You are welcome!

Comment: On IIS10 the 'Logging' feature requires that at least the `World Wide Web Services -> Health and Diagnostics -> HTTP Logging` windows feature is installed. Otherwise it will not show up.

Comment: Any what if the Logging icon doesn't appear?  I can't find my log files locally - none of the paths seem to exist on my machine.

Answer (score 112):

I'm adding this answer because after researching the web, I ended up at this answer but still didn't know which *subfolder* of the IIS logs folder to look in.

If your server has multiple websites, you will need to know the IIS ID for the site. An easy way to get this in IIS is to simply click on the *Sites* folder in the left panel.  The ID for each site is shown in the right panel.

Once you know the ID, let's call it *n*,  the corresponding logs are in the W3SVC*n* subfolder of the IIS logs folder. So, if your website ID is 4, say, and the IIS logs are in the *default* location, then the logs are in this folder:

```
%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC4
```

Acknowlegements:

- Answer by @jishi tells where the logs are by default.
- Answer by @Rafid explains how to find actual location (maybe not default).
- Answer by @Bergius gives a programmatic way to find the log folder location for a specific website, taking ID into account, without using IIS.

Comment: I found the ID by clicking on advanced settings in the Actions Panel after selecting the site in the Connections panel.

Answer (score 19):

The 100% correct answer for the default location of the log files is...

```
%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles
```

Yes you can enter this into the explorer address bar it'll work.

To be 100% sure, you need to look at the logging for the web site in IIS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/enhanced-logging-for-iis85

i.e.

1. Open IIS Manager.
2. Select the site or server in the Connections pane,
3. Double-click Logging.
4. The location of log files for the site can be found within the Directory field

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Andy in the comments below you need to ensure when installing IIS that you elected to enable HTTP logging, otherwise HTTP logging won't be available.

[image: Enable HTTP Logging]

Answer (score 12):

A much easier way to do this is using PowerShell, like so:

```
Get-Website yoursite | % { Join-Path ($_.logFile.Directory -replace '%SystemDrive%', $env:SystemDrive) "W3SVC$($_.id)" }
```

or simply

```
Get-Website yoursite | % { $_.logFile.Directory, $_.id }
```

if you just need the info for yourself and don't mind parsing the result in your brain :).

For bonus points, append `| ii` to the first command to open in Explorer, or `| gci` to list the contents of the folder.

Comment: No, wait, it's:
(Get-Website * | % { $_.logFile.Directory})

Answer (score 6):

Try the Windows event log, there can be some useful information

Comment: The event log will probably have any page errors that occurs on the site.

Comment: Seems like a good idea, but there is a great deal of info here, and I can't seem to find anything relevant to IIS. Any pointer as to where in the Event Viewer to look, or how best to filter the information there?

Comment: -1, reason: this answer is too general. Please provide a detailed explanation where in the event log the information can be found, or how to filter for it, otherwise given the huge amount of logs in the logs in the event log its too difficult to find the relevant logs.

Comment: Found the cause of my issue (connection closed only on *.woff files) in Windows Logs > System (in my case a wrong SSL configuration)

Answer (score 4):

Enabling [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) may be a better alternative to the Windows Event Log.  This gave me the information I needed to fix my own WebService.

Answer (score 3):

I think the Default place for IIS logging is: `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\log\w3svc`

Answer (score 1):

I have found the IIS Log files at the following location.

> C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\

which help to fix my issue.

Comment: I have just provided the default path where IIS log files lie on the server. If you can read the question. It is "Where does IIS7 store logs by default?" :(

Answer (score 0):

C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles

Check the identity of the site going to sites and advanced settings

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to query like this:

```
(Get-Website * | % { $_.logFile.Directory});ls $GetIISLogs\W3SVC1\*
```

If you have more than one site you will get more than one answer, so you need to query with a 'foreach' to get the website name with the directory...