# IIS7 + PHP5.3.16 + Plesk how to get detailed info for 500 error?

Tags: php, iis, logging, iis-7, plesk

I have installed Plesk Panel with PHP5.2.17 on the Windows 7 + IIS7 machine and it was working well. But I have replaced to PHP5.3.16 and check over php.ini. But I get 500 error now. 
How I can get detailed info about error ? Where is error log located? I have trying to see access log on server panel (IIS/Logging icon) but there are only access lines logged. I have tried to make "log_errors=On and log_error=syslog" but I can not see any related records in system  log.

Comment: [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426375/where-do-i-find-the-iis7-logs) should answer where error logs are located.

Answer (score 2):

The following post should assist:

[Display PHP error messages on IIS 7.0 / 7.5](http://blogs.staykov.net/2010/06/display-php-error-messages-on-iis-70-75.html)

Comment: I have made all these recommended changes, it shows "Config was changed" but I can't see any error messages written in log files (I think I've probably check it all).