# Site rebuilt and IIS stopped working

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

I've been helping a client rebuild a website that is hosted on a IIS 6 (I think) after he fired its IT Director.
One of the tasks was to change all the passwords for DB access, which went just fine.

Given this, we had to recompile the web application/site to reflect these changes (new user/password) and we tried rebuilding the web site (which went fine) and then placing the files on the same folder as the previous ones were, basically replacing what was on the server.

But now, the site won't work at all giving just a bad request and I can't seem to be able to fix this.
I've never used IIS before and the configurations done are the very basic ones (almost nothing really) so I can't seem to understand why this doesn't work.

Could anyone give a hand?

Thanks,
BR

Comment: check your IIS log,and post the results of the bad request. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426375/where-can-i-find-the-iis-logs

Comment: try to register aspnet_regiis -i from the Microsoft.net folder and then see if it works or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out this problem was split in two parts that were causing the problem.

Number 1 was that the Web.config file wasn't properly setup to a production environment and thus causing inaccessibility problems.
Number 2 was that for some reason IIS was set to use ASP.NET v2 and the website was built using .NET 4. Although this shouldn't be a problem it was causing some other problems.

IF someone ever gets caught in the same problem, it's worth checking out these two items, at least, and do a IIS Reset.