# 500 Internal Server Error - PHP and IIS

Tags: php, windows, iis

I'm running `PHP 5.4.24` On `IIS-7` server. when I export huge size of record Im getting `500 internal server error`. It send a message

> 500 Error has occurred for this request

and suddenly stop the website. I tried in APACHE with same code but I could not get any error. Its getting download successfully.

Please assist me on this, Is there any setting I need to change in IIS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first: check the logfiles

Comment: I checked but nothing is there in the log file

Comment: Then i think you are out of luck, nobody is going to wildly guess or use a crystal ball to solve this. Are you sure you checked the right file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426375/where-can-i-find-the-iis-logs

Comment: it showing like this : GET /index.php?ajax&request=giske&mjx=0.47372315481925603&site=giske&gisHome=home&&retiredFilter=no&statusView=no 503 2 N/A giske.dev

Comment: this seems to be rather common, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322937/iis-http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable or follow the suggestsions from here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1183179.aspx?Service+Unavailable+HTTP+Error+503+The+service+is+unavailable+