# One website on IIS server cannot connect to SMTP host - how to track what happened

Tags: email, iis, asp-classic, smtp

I have an ASP website on an IIS server, yesterday I noticed that this certain website was unable to send out any emails as Dynumail (something we use for SMTP emails in code) could not connect to the SMTP host.

This issue was only happening with this website and not any of the others on the same server that also use Dynumail.

Is there a way to track how this might have happened? To resolve the issue I restarted the website through the IIS GUI.

Any help on tracking down (and preventing) this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's a third party component - does website's IUSR account have the necessary permissions on the component's dll?  Other than that check thoroughly for typos in your code, especially in smtp addresses, recipient addresses etc

Comment: Hi there, the thing is it was running smoothly before this. No code changes etc. The problem was resolved by simply restarting the website. But I really would like to know what might have caused this so I can prevent it from happening again. So having resolved it without touching the code, it does indicate that it probably isn't any of those things.

Comment: You might find error messages in your server logs - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426375/where-can-i-find-the-iis-logs

Comment: Hi John, I've tried looking at both SMTP logs and website logs but no luck.