# Actual IP hits on website

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

How can I know what the actual IPs of who open the site or hit on server from IIS Logs or Windows Firewall Logs or other way?

Windows Version : Windows Server 2008 R2 DataCenter 
IIS Version : 7.5

Comment: Try if a slight different version of linux command could be used: `awk '{print $1}' PATH_TO_THE_ACCESS_LOG|sort -u` ? Also check for solution here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/iis-access-log-to-sql-normalization

Comment: Do you want to do it from you [code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net) or do you want to look for [log files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426375/where-can-i-find-the-iis-logs)?

Comment: Șhȇkhaṝ  log is not saving the actual ip  saving always 10.1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

its simple you can use this function 
to find the ip of the client

```
string ipaddress;
        ipaddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        if (ipaddress == "" || ipaddress == null)
            ipaddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

hope it will help you bye

Comment: You can not be sure that this is a actual IP this can be IP of the firewall etc.

Comment: but this can be actual IP

Comment: no its not that simple ,, ive tried that before and i tried that again not retrieving actual IP

Comment: All Functions or logs used on get IPs is  working well if you are using another ports not http port 80 , on 80 not working