# IIS 7 Error in windows server

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7.5, .net-framework-version

Can any one help my to fix following error i setup .Netframwork the IIS and register asp.net (aspnet_regiis.exe -i)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqucW.png)

Comment: Is there a more detailed error in the Event Log?

Comment: Add some exception detaling here.

Comment: where i can error from event log?

Comment: Which Windows you are using, XP support has ended, no updates?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: log: %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426375/where-can-i-find-the-iis-logs and http://serverfault.com/questions/91673/where-how-can-i-see-iis7-log-entries-for-a-specific-web-site

Comment: the all text document empty

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you hit this issue and need to take some special steps,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2014/10/28/case-study-http-error-500-0-internal-server-error-from-aspnetinitclrhostfailuremodule.aspx

> **Root Cause**
>
> Although the .NET 4.0 was installed on this computer, the version of
>   %windir%\system32\mscoree.dll was still v2.0. It should be replaced
>   with v4.0.
>
> It loads .NET 2.0 runtime mscorwks.dll, not the .NET 4.0 runtime
>   clr.dll. Therefore some unexpected behaviors occur during the CLR
>   initialization that causes the worker process to be recycled.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> You can reinstall .NET 4.0 or re-apply Windows 2008 R2 SP1 to update
>   mscoree.dll.