# PHP not able to connect to database

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to Create a simple webservice (written in PHP)  for android which make a Db Call to SQL Server and it is deployed on IIS

```
<?php

$serverName = "MyDB/Instance"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"MyDB", "UID"=>"MYID", "PWD"=>"MyPWD");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


$tsql = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployee";  

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);  

if ( $stmt )  
{  
     echo "Statement executed.<br>\n";  
}   
else   
{  
     echo "Error in statement execution.\n";  

     die( print_r( "Error", true));  
}  

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))  
{  
     echo "Col1: ".$row[0]."\n";  
     echo "Col2: ".$row[1]."\n";  
     echo "Col3: ".$row[2]."<br>\n";  
     echo "-----------------<br>\n";  
}  

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  
sqlsrv_close( $conn);  
?>
```

................
My Browser simply not supporting this

[image]

My Port is working fine

[image]

This is My Error Log Found on C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC11

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2016-07-05 07:38:34
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2016-07-05 07:38:34 ::1 GET / - 8092 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/51.0.2704.103+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 31402
2016-07-05 07:38:34 ::1 GET /Content/site.css - 8092 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/51.0.2704.103+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:8092/ 200 0 0 1
2016-07-05 07:38:34 ::1 GET /Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js - 8092 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/51.0.2704.103+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:8092/ 200 0 0 104
2016-07-05 07:38:34 ::1 GET /Content/bootstrap.css - 8092 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/51.0.2704.103+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:8092/ 200 0 0 117
2016-07-05 07:38:34 ::1 GET /Scripts/respond.js - 8092 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/51.0.2704.103+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:8092/ 200 0 0 115
2016-07-05 07:38:34 ::1 GET /Scripts/bootstrap.js - 8092 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/51.0.2704.103+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:8092/ 200 0 0 116
2016-07-05 07:38:34 ::1 GET /Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js - 8092 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/51.0.2704.103+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:8092/ 200 0 0 366
2016-07-05 07:38:36 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 8092 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/51.0.2704.103+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:8092/ 200 0 0 38
2016-07-05 07:39:01 ::1 GET /select.php - 8092 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/51.0.2704.103+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 817
2016-07-05 07:39:52 ::1 GET /select.php - 8092 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/51.0.2704.103+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 30
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2016-07-05 08:22:23
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2016-07-05 08:22:23 ::1 GET / - 8092 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/51.0.2704.103+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 4699
2016-07-05 08:22:34 ::1 GET /select.php - 8092 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/51.0.2704.103+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 480
2016-07-05 08:25:56 ::1 GET / - 8092 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/51.0.2704.103+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 8
```

I tried to run on another browser , but it also got unresponsive

I am not able to diagnose the Error that what wrong happening inside ?
I found some article to rightly connect php Page with Sql Server , and I Believe My Code is right , Still Not able to find the cause ,

Comment: Error 500 means an internal server error. To diagnose, you need to know what the error is. This means finding the error log, and reading it. To find the log maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426375/where-can-i-find-the-iis-logs. Most likely `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`

Comment: Tx for suggestion , I updated My error Log

Comment: That looks like an access log, not an error log

Comment: Thats what I found on the given path

Comment: Maybe read the approved answer to the question I linked above - it has stuff about editing php.ini as well, which might be helpful. Until you can see what the error is, there's nothing anyone can really do.

Comment: try to avoid html tags in webService

Comment: I believe I dont have additional HTML tags

Comment: You have **2** `sqlsrv_connect()` statement in that code, one after the other. Could that have something to do with your problem

Comment: Yes I am into Dot net and Learning android and PHP , I removed Typo Error , but that doesnt making difference

Comment: How about checking if the connection was established or not ? Then exit if connection wasn't set.

Comment: Nope . I checked that , Still same

Comment: The way I debug these kind of errors is to comment out all the code and then uncomment 1 or 2 lines of code and run it, then uncomment another 1 or 2 lines etc etc. When you get the crash, you know where the issue is

Comment: does any php code works? i mean just echoing out something from php file works?

Comment: Nope , Nothing . it is just stuck on "Page not working" .. I think it is not about PHP code

Comment: i think you have not  installed it correctly on iis then. try this [link](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php) and see if simple php code works

Comment: IIS is fine , I already told you that other sites are working on IIS

Comment: you mean all other php files on iis; except this one, are working fine?

Comment: if not there might be php installation problem on your server. iis can run without php. but any php file wont..

Comment: I Got your point , I am Re -installing PHP on IIS , will let you know