# Image path, src diacritics, php

Tags: php, html, laravel

**EDIT 1:** I have created a new laravel project just blank one and diacritics also doesn't work, meta char is included.

Html code:

```
 <div class="row">
    @foreach ($TagNames as $TagName)
        <div  class="col-sm-4">
            <p>{{$TagName->TagName}}</p>
            <img style="min-width:35%; min-height:35%"; class="img-responsive"; src="images/{{$TagName->TagName}}.jpg"> 
        </div>
    @endforeach
      </div>
```

Everything works fine for getting images until the path name has some diacritics (romanian ones î,â,ț,ă,ș), I tried adding

```
<img style="min-width:35%; min-height:35%"; class="img-responsive"; src="images/Dude1withî.jpg">
```

and it doesn't work too.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Is added but doesn't do anything.

Examples of images stored in **images** folder:

```
Măr.png, Pîine.png, Pastă.png and so on
```

How can I solve this? Any given help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the problem? Is it with php outputting the correct name, The browser not able to deal with the special chars, or is the webserver having a problem with the request? There are many points of failure here.

Comment: Inspected the page gives the normal path with diacritics, but It doesn't retrieve the image

Comment: I tried without php outputting, like so src="images/Dude1withî.jpg" with (î), and doesn't work too

Comment: I am using localhost, the images are stored in laravelproject/public/images/, normal images without diacritics works, idk

Comment: Can you put the img path in the browser address bar directly? Also check the webserer error log.

Comment: I tried putting it manually, doesn't work too although for names without diacritics works, webserver error log how to do it?

Comment: For iis http://stackoverflow.com/a/6426399/4178487 or for Apache /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: use url('images/'.{{$TagName->TagName}}.'.jpg') helper function to get the full correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If your images directory is placed in laravel root update the code below with asset() function. Try,

```
<img style="min-width:35%; min-height:35%"; class="img-responsive"; src="{{ asset('images/Dude1withî.jpg') }}" />
```

Will work. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work, seems like laravel doesn't like diacritics, with apache(xampp) blank project one works fine