# Codeigniter Controller link is not working in IIS

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, controller

I created a web site and hosted in an IIS server, but there I cannot access my site's inner links.

For example: `http://example.com/about` where 'about' is the controller.

Here `http://example.com` is working well, but `http://example.com/about` returns a 404 error.

Comment: Did you've removed **index.php** via `htaccess`? Try `http://example.com/index.php/about`

Comment: you need to look at your .htaccess file

Comment: Check security group permissions on the subfolder, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934006/iis-iusrs-and-iusr-permissions-in-iis8

Comment: For the commenters stating to use .htaccess: IIS doesn't use .htaccess, .htaccess is for Apache web servers.

Comment: @OP also check your IIS error log, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426375/where-can-i-find-the-iis-logs to find out where your log file should be. The path to your log file must be configured in IIS.

Comment: 404 is showing while giving link http://example.com/about

Comment: Have you verified the correct security groups are set on the `about` folder? Windows/IIS can behave a bit weird with permissioning, like subdirectories or files having different security groups than their parent folder. Or sometimes even a program will change the security groups, depending on how the program saves a file, which is what I've experienced with phpstorm at one time.

Comment: 'about' is not a folder it is one controller file

Comment: So either you need to turn on PHP error reporting and debug the error you receive, or check the IIS error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to hosted the Codeigniter in the IIS, you need to add some special url rewrite rule to let your application work well.

I suggest you could install the url rewrite extension for the IIS firstly.

Then I suggest you could try to add below rule into the web.config.

```
  <system.webServer>

    <rewrite>

      <rules>

          <rule name="Index">

          <match url="^(.*)$" />

          <conditions>

            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />

            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />

          </conditions>

                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />

        </rule>

      </rules>

    </rewrite>

  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I was not using a web.config file, Without web.config home page is loading .