# Visual Studio 2015 IIS Express 500 Error

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015

I have an ASP.Net website project that I am migrating to .Net 4.6.1 .

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Community, and I have successfully compiled and built both the website and its component DLL.

When I try to use IIS Express to debug with F5, I get a 500 error...

`HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
Tracing area "Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,Rewrite,RequestRouting" is not recognized`

That says to me that IIS Express does not have a module installed that I need.  I thought it might be that ARR and URL Rewrite were not installed, so I installed these, no change.

My ApplicationPool in production uses PreWarmCache technology to start up and avoid 'first hit' delays, and do other one-time startup work.

Help with getting IIS Express to run the site would be very useful.

Comment: Are you running the ASP.NET code as a site or an application (within the site)?  Can you also implement the "Application_Error" method (in Global) in your ASP.NET application and post the exception you're getting?

Comment: Good suggestion, but I have implemented Application_Error in Global.ASAX, and this is not getting called.  I have put a breakpoint in the function and a log line for the exception held in Server.GetLastError(), and I get nothing.  The 500 notification has additional diags, I will post up and google some more. Thx.

Comment: <QUOTE>

Module:FailedRequestsTracingModule
Notification:BeginRequest
Handler:ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0
Error Code:0x80070057
Requested URL:http://localhost:49605/
Physical Path:C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HTML\ProjectName\Website
Logon Method:Not yet determined
Logon User:Not yet determined
Request Tracing Directory:C:\Users\User\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\WEBSITE

This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred.
KB:294807

</QUOTE>

Comment: I have tried de-installing and re-installing IIS Express 10.0 x64, no joy.  I have tried forcing a rebuild of the applicationHost.config file in both the IIS Express config directory, and the projects local hidden vs directory.  I have tried removing the trace elements referenced in the error from the config, no joy.

Comment: I have the same bug after getting the latest windows 10 patch.

Comment: Maybe it help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122240/why-am-i-getting-error-500-0-in-when-using-iis-express-significant-debug-info-i

Comment: @LewisHai: Thanks, I had a similar problem to the one in the link, but with WOFF files, but that was resolved.  I think I have a solution now, Cahit's answer below, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @ThreeValueLogic: Give Cahit answer below a try, make sure you check for the setting in both your web.config AND the IIS Express applicationhost.config file that is specific to your project, and good luck.

Comment: Installing Visual Studio 2015 solved it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a line like this in your web.config file, can you remove it and try to run it again?

```
<add provider="WWW Server"
    areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,Rewrite,RequestRouting" 
    verbosity="Verbose" />
```

Comment: I did have this in my web.config.  This did not immediately fix the issue, but it got me thinking.  I had to remove the line above from the project's local IIS Express config file too.  NOTE!  The applicationHost.config file is in a hidden folder under your project directory called ".vs".  Changing the central file for IIS might also be a good idea if you start new projects.  Thanks @Cahit, I am now working with IIS Express, bounty earned, hope this helps others too.

Comment: What if I want that line to be there... If you want that line to be there, it means that there is one or more Area that is not supported by your IIS server. Mine was "iisnode"

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to get the blank page and 500 errors due to a problem with Visual Studio's project migration. Closing the solution and deleting the `.vs` folder can remedy this.