# IIS Express Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I am having a problem with IIS Express 7.5 on one my machines that I cannot track down.

Running IIS Express 7.5
Studio 2010 
.NET 3.5 Framework
ASP.NET MVC Website (default)

I have successfully changed the site over to use IIS Express and it runs fine that way on 2 different development machines.

When I try it on a 3rd machine I get a 500 error (following)

I have looked through the excellend post:
[HTTP 500 Internal Error - IIS websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416068/http-500-internal-error-iis-websites)

But that solution seems to not work on .NET 3.5

I have also looked for log files (not generated) and at the Events log (none errors)

Ideas?

Confused Tom

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Most likely causes:
IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:
Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
Verify the permissions for the DLL.
Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
Check the failed request tracing logs for additional information about this error. For more information, click here.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x80070585
Requested URL      http://127.0.0.1:58365/
Physical Path      
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
Request Tracing Directory      C:\Users\Digineerian\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\

More Information:
This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.
View more information »

Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

294807
```

Comment: Did you check request tracing logs located in "C:\Users\Digineerian\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles"? Any interesting info that log files?