# IIS dll error 500

Tags: asp.net, iis, dll

I'm working on an asp.Net project. I developed an aspx page which uses dll that I was provided.

When I tested under Visual Studio (2015) it works very well.

I'm trying my page under IIS (localhost) I have an error 500.

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>
> Failed to call GetProcAddress on the ISAPI filter "C: \ inetpub \
>   wwwroot \ ViaTrajectoryTest \ ViaTrajectoryTest \ Hl7.Fhir.Core.dll"

Any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP 500 Internal Error - IIS websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416068/http-500-internal-error-iis-websites)

Comment: The error message is super clear that an invalid ISAPI filter is registered. Create a valid filter please.